# name 'version' is not defined (Python and Visual Studio Code)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

As the titel says, I am very new to python and I'm trying to get some API's and other irrelevant stuff to work. The only problem is that pip is imported (I think) but I don't seem to be able to use it. Here is my code:

```
import pip

pip --version
```

As you see, it's nothing special. Here is the exact error message I'm getting: 
Exception has occurred: NameError
name 'version' is not defined

Comment: Oh just saw that this is a duplicate, should I remove it or leave it up (with the correct answer in the comments)?

Comment: Did you try `pip.__version__` instead of `pip --version`?

Answer (score 2):

Pip is a package manager rather than a module. Try running pip --version inside a terminal window rather than a python shell

Comment: That's correct! Thanks for the help, I'll mark this is solved as soon as I can!